# Laptop DVD-ROM opens on its own

Tags: windows-7, optical-drive

My DVD-ROM opens from time to time. When I am surfing on web or watching movie, my DVD-ROM just opens. I am using windows 7 (32-bit). Laptop is E-machines G620.
driver Microsoft, driver version 6.1.7601.17514; Device Status : This device is working properly.
I have tryed to install/uninstall, enable/disable but still having the same problem. 
Full scan with Avast and AVG - nothing found.

Comment: Did you want to include a question? Maybe some more details?

Comment: What details do you need? Registry enterises.. I dont know what else should I include?

Comment: A question and trouble shooting performed to date to try and resolve your issue

Comment: I have Troubleshoot "Hardware and devices" and there were no problems

Comment: You aren't being [pranked](http://www.wikihow.com/Play-a-Computer-Caps-Lock-and-CD-Tray-Prank) are you?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with a Dell laptop, which was caused by some hardware (really physical) problem, since the drive opened when I put some pressure on the left part of the laptop, just on top of drive's position.

Do your drive open even when you are not touching or moving it?

You might try running a Ubuntu live-cd (no installation) for some hours to check if the same happens, and discard (or not) a hardware problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of a virus that does this. Try updating your antivirus databases. Either that or your being pranked. My memory is a little foggy. I think there is a VBScript that makes this happen.

Try the following path:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```